# How to create an asymmetric triangle at the bottom left corner of a box?

Tags: html, css

I need to create a box with an arrow at the left bottom corner. My problem is to get the asymmetric triangle.

Here an example for the bottom border of the box with an triangle at the left bottom corner:

[image: Example]

This is my attempt so far:

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px;
  float: left;
}

.box.arrow-bottom:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: -15px;
  border-top: 15px solid black;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box arrow-bottom">
  This is a box with some content and an arrow at the bottom.
</div>
```

Comment: Can you seperate the html and the javascript so we can run the code

Comment: Change the dupe to `.comment:before {
  background-color: skyblue;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 40px;
}` to point the other way

Comment: If you want it to the left why do you set `right:30px` and not `left:0` ? :)

Comment: @MihaiT Sorry, this was a copy error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited the border width a bit, and added `transform: skewX()`. You may play with the right amount for the skew. 
In addition the `:after` changed to `:before` and I played with `left` property and removed the `right`.
hope it helps:

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px;
  float: left;
}

.box.arrow-bottom:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  bottom: -15px;
  border-top: 15px solid black;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: none;
  transform: skewX(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box arrow-bottom">
  This is a box with some content and an arrow at the bottom.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write below code to generate arrow

```
.box {
position: relative;
background: #00aabb;
border-radius: .4em;
}

.box:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0%;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 20px solid transparent;
border-top-color: #00aabb;
border-bottom: 0;
border-right: 0;
margin-left: -10px;
margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

Comment: To get an asymmetric triangle as requested, I would suggest setting `margin-left` to `5px` and to use a CSS transform such as `transform: skew(30deg)`. Live example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cjake/x7mjdft8/)

Comment: Yes, you can do with the transform also.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea using multiple background and relying on [`conic-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/conic-gradient) <sup>1</sup>

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  background: 
    conic-gradient(transparent 314deg, black 315deg,black 340deg,transparent 342deg)
    bottom -30px left 0/60px 60px border-box,     
    black padding-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom:30px solid transparent; /*the space for the gradient*/
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box arrow-bottom">
  This is a box with some content and an arrow at the bottom.
</div>
```

Here is the gradient alone to better see how it's working:

```css
.box {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: 
    conic-gradient(red 314deg, black 315deg,black 340deg,red 342deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

<sup>1:Supported only on chrome actually</sup>

---

Another idea with `linear-gradient` but without transparency:

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49%,#fff 50%) bottom 0 left 0/30px 30px border-box,
    linear-gradient(250deg, transparent 10px,#000 11px) bottom 0 left 0/30px 30px border-box,     
    black padding-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom:30px solid transparent; /*the space for the gradient*/
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box arrow-bottom">
  This is a box with some content and an arrow at the bottom.
</div>
```

Comment: Looks perfect. Exactly what I need, but unfortunately there is only chrome supported, which is not an option for me...

Comment: @user3142695 yes we still need to wait a bit but it's coming ;) it will soon be supported everywhere. I have also added another idea with simple gradient but without transparency

Answer (score 0):

You could use an SVG as the background of the pseudoelement, e.g.

```
.box.arrow-bottom:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: -30px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #000;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 22 30" 
                   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
                   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
                   <path d="M0 0 L22 30 L15 0 z" fill="%23000" /></svg>');
}
```

> [Example Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LvgeXb?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated css with `transform:rotate` and `border`, check it

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px;
  float: left;
}

.box.arrow-bottom:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: 7px;
  bottom: -41px;
  border-top: 45px solid black;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 0px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}

.box.arrow-bottom:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 7px;
  bottom: -41px;
  border-top: 45px solid black;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: none;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box arrow-bottom">
  This is a box with some content and an arrow at the bottom.
</div>
```