# How to create a zig zag pattern using CSS

Tags: html, css, background, linear-gradients

On a repeated background, the edges of the repeated tiles don't align exactly on certain zoom levels. This leads to unwanted edges as the color of the background is visible in this 1px gap.

I've done some background reading and understand this is probably due to a rounding error on decimal pixel values due to the zooming. Adjusting the size of the background tile by a couple of pixels removes the issue at one zoom level (as the scaled image dimension are then integer values), but obviously breaks other zoom values.

Slightly overlapping the background tiles might work, but I'm not sure how this can be achieved with a repeated background . Disabling zoom is another option, but I would like to prevent this if possible.

Code as shown below shows the problem in Chrome when setting the zoom to 85% (or even worse on 63%):

```css
#header {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ECEDDC 24.9%, transparent 25.1%) -70px 0,
              linear-gradient(225deg, #ECEDDC 24.9%, transparent 25.1%) -70px 0,
              linear-gradient(315deg, #ECEDDC 24.9%, transparent 25.1%),
              linear-gradient(45deg, #ECEDDC 24.9%, transparent 25.1%);
  background-size: 140px 140px;
  background-color: #29AB87;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
```

Screenshot of the issue:

[image]

Comment: not easy to fix this .. probably an SVG would give better result

Comment: That would indeed be the other option, which the other answers also seem to point to. SVG it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a different idea to create this using [`conic-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/conic-gradient) that may reduce this bad effect since we will rely on only two gradients

```css
body {
  background: 
   conic-gradient(
    #ECEDDC 0 0.125turn,
    transparent 0.126turn 0.874turn,
    #ECEDDC 0.875turn 1turn),
   conic-gradient(
    transparent 0 0.375turn,
    #ECEDDC 0.376turn 0.624turn,
    transparent 0.625turn 1turn) 70px 0.8px,
   #29AB87;

  background-size: 140px 140px;
  margin:0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

You will notice that I am using a slight difference of `0.001turn` in the color stops to avoid jagged edges and I also translated the second gradient by `0.8px` to create a small overlap and avoid gaps.

---

For better support and better rendering consider SVG like below:

```css
body {
  background: 
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" ><polygon fill="%23ECEDDC" points="0,0  20,0  10,10"/></svg>'), 
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" ><polygon fill="%23ECEDDC" points="0,20 20,20 10,10"/></svg>') 70px 0,
   #29AB87;

  background-size: 140px 140px;
  margin:0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: @KyleMit let's increase more then .. but we may notice a small drawback in the shape

Comment: Stilly *tiny tiny* bit of [wonkiness at 67%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kBO2.png)

Comment: @KyleMit let's hope no one will zoom at this level ;)

Comment: Thanks for providing the different approach, but seems a bit backwards to useconic-gradient for what is essentially a collection of straight lines. Weird that this doesn't have the same issue as line-gradient. I'll be going with your SVG approach. @KyleMit thanks for the answer as well!

Comment: @mvr there is nothing *backwards* in using conic-gradient() to draw lines ;) it's even more powerful to use it to draw lines better linear-gradient() ... let's wait for it to have better support and you will see all the magic we can do with (ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55455760/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/56212104/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/55826949/8620333)

Answer (score 2):

Using a full page SVG with an internal repeating pattern seems to scale the most smoothly

```css
html, body {  margin: 0; }
svg { position: absolute; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">  
  <pattern id="p1" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  >
    <polygon points="0,0 5,5 10,0 10,5 5,10, 0,5" fill="#ECEDDC" /> 
  </pattern>
 
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#29AB87"  />
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#p1)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: you have a little typo: missing `;` after height declaration (probably not need at all by the way)